# Change OpenLayers 3 view center

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system, coordinates, epsg, openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers 3 to interact with some maps. I first declare my map:

```
map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
              new ol.layer.Tile({
                  source: new ol.source.OSM()
              })
                ],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 2
            })
        });
```

I've an event that triggers an action, to change my map's view center. This way, (my coordinates are in `EPSG:4326` format):

```
function CenterMap(lat, long) {
     console.log("Lat: " + lat + " Long: " + long);
     map.setView(new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.transform([lat, long], 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'),
            zoom: 5
     }));
}
```

When the function runs I get this at the explorer console:

```
Lat: 9.0412851667 Long: -79.5658145000
```

But the maps goes to `[0,0]`, does anyone knows why this happen?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In ol.proj.transform you need to specify the fromProjection before the toProjection, then it should work.

As Michael Gentry explains in his answer, another Problem is that you have to specify the longitude (west-east thus x) first and then the latitude (south-north thus y).

And a better way to set the center is to get the current view and set the center there instead of always creating a new one.

```
function CenterMap(long, lat) {
    console.log("Long: " + long + " Lat: " + lat);
    map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.transform([long, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
    map.getView().setZoom(5);
}
```

Comment: Ok I got it thanks. One more thing, if I change it that way I'm getting a new error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'putImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': float parameter 3 is non-finite. ol.js:457
2Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length`. And I think is because my coordinates are too long. If I change it for `[131.044922, -25.363882]` it works ok. So are my coordinates too long??

Comment: that should not be the problem. what coordinates did the error occur with? the ones you mentioned above?

Comment: yes the one there

Comment: I tried these coordinates with a MapQuest map and it did work. A longitude of -79 is still within the bounds of EPSG:4326 (within +/-90 degrees) and EPSG:3857 (within +/-85 degrees).

Comment: its a typeerror occuring inside of the renderer and a rangerror

Comment: hmm. maybe you would like to add the following line to the beginning of the function and tell me the output?
`console.log(typeof lat + " " + typeof long + " ");`

or pass more of the code, i could try to find the error or bug.

Comment: Note that you can use `ol.proj.fromLonLat([long,lat])` for the same result but with slightly improved readability

Answer (score 9):

I have a new stack exchange account and don't have a reputation high enough to comment on the "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'putImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': float parameter 3 is non-finite." error. This occurs because you have the lat and the long inputs backwards.

```
map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.transform([lat, long], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
```

should be:

```
map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.transform([long, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
```

in case anyone else has this problem.

Comment: yes you're right - i will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

For browser-only use :

```
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js'></script>


  ol.proj.transform() 

  ol.proj.transform([long, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

For js-app use

```
   // for projection
  import {transform} from 'ol/proj.js';

  // use this one : transform([-118.246521, 34.049039], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')





   var map = new Map({
    layers: layers,
    target: 'map',
    view: new View({
      //center: [-118.246521, 34.049039],
        center: transform([-118.246521, 34.049039], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      zoom: 16
    })
  });
```