# Set Center of Openlayers3 to location of click?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Is it possible to get openlayers3 to center the map on the location of a click?

Don't have any code to show as i am just curious and can't seem to find any information regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search and I found this example to get the mouse coordinates:

https://openlayersbook.github.io/ch09-taking-control-of-controls/example-03.html

and this example to set the center of the map:

[Change OpenLayers 3 view center](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112892/change-openlayers-3-view-center)

After you implement this code, please feel free to post a new question.

Comment: thanks for that, will try implement later and if i have issues will post up.
Cheers

Answer (score 5):

I've just had the same issue and used @kttii's answer to solve it.

```
function myZoom() {
    myView = new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([ -46.604057, -23.542679 ],"EPSG:4326","EPSG:3857"), zoom: 11 });
    map.setView(myView);
}
```

Now, just add the call to `myZoom()` to your trigger (mine is a button):

```
 <button onclick="myZoom()">Click me to zoom!</button>
```